# find out if value fron a JSON was a boolean (true/false)

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, json, boolean

I'm coding a category on NSManagedObject so it can populates its attributes itself from a NSDictionnary I have from a JSON (via NSJSONSerialization)

My problem is: if the original value is true or false, it is converted to NSNumber, but I want to insert it in the managed object as a BOOL (I'm aware of boolValue) if, and only if it was originally a BOOL and not a number.
So far, my related code is :

```
if ([value isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]])
        {
            if (NSClassFromString(@"__NSCFBoolean") && [value isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"__NSCFBoolean")]) {
                [self setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:[value boolValue]] forKey:key];
            } else if (NSClassFromString(@"NSCFBoolean") && [value isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"NSCFBoolean")]) {
                [self setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:[value boolValue]] forKey:key];
            } else {
                [self setValue:value forKey:key];
            }
        }
```

I get the error :

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key myJsonOriginalKeyName

Again, my managed object has a boolean attribute for the corresponding key when it's value id true/false in the original JSON
How can I automatically determine if I should convert value to a BOOL or NSNumber

Comment: In which line exactly is it thown? 
Please nslog(@"self: %@",self);

Comment: The entity of the managed object you are calling setValue:forKey: on doesn't have an attribute named "myJsonOriginalKeyName".

Comment: This log displays my managedObject class name "self: Player"

Comment: exeption thrown at the first
 [self setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:[value boolValue]] forKey:key];

Comment: Nicholas, I have checked this, it does have such a property (actual name is "linked")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am doing this right now in my app, its sort of - well - not completely sanctioned, but it seems to work just fine using NSJSONSerialization in iOS7:

```
if(strcmp([num objCType], "c") == 0) {
   // its a boolean
   ...
```

The caveat us that Apple says in the Class Description that you cannot count on this to be consistent. That said, if NSJSONSerialization is only using a method to convert bools that results in this type, it probably won't change any time soon.

Comment: NSLog(@"%d", strcmp([value objCType], "c")); displays 0

Thanks. But this doesn't work (same error), I must be ;issing something,
Maybe the reason id related to the fact the code I posted is from 
@implementation NSManagedObject (Category)
and then called by an instance of one of my managed objects to self

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. My point was that in the original JSON object, when its converted, you can by looking at that see if a value was a boolean (most likely). Once you import that into Core Data, obviously that is lost. Maybe I misunderstood your question. What I suggest here is a way to know if the JSON value was a boolean. If you need to insure that is replicated in Core Data, make it a string of value "YES" or "NO", and if not a "c" type then make it a string with a numeric field.

Comment: Yes that was my question, but I just tested to add @"test" in the object at the same place in my code after re generating the class with a string field instead of a boolean, and I still get the same error, so I guess my problem is not the one I thought first, your trick may be right, but it seems I actually missed something else

Comment: OK, the problem is that i'm sending the message to self in a NSManagedObject category, so it sends it to NSMAnagedObject instead of my own subclass of it.
I fixed it by adding a parameter to send setValue:ForKey: to (which is set to self), but it's somehow weird I guess. 
Your trick works fine.